# How do I calculate the number of occurrences from Column A, based on value of column B in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
A        Pass
A        Fail
A        Pass
B        Fail
A        Fail
C        Open
D        Fail
B        Fail
B        Pass
D        Open
E        Pass
```

I need to show each of Column A as a column with the count of values from Column B, in a stacked bar chart:

First bar: 2(Pass)+2(Fail)

Second bar:  1(Pass)+2(Fail)

... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you just create a simple measure like this:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[ColumnB]))
```

Then select a stacked bar chart from the visualizations pane, and configure like this:

[image]

You should get this:

[image]

Which I think, is what you are looking for.

Hope that helps!!